# Find equation of line(s) bisecting perimeter and area of triangle formed by $xy$-axes and $6x+8y=48$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

The line $6x+8y=48$ intersects the $x$-axis in point $A$ and the $y$-axis in point $B$. A line $L$ bisects the area and the perimeter of the triangle $OAB$,where $O$ is origin.

Find possible equation(s) of $L$.

**My Attempt**

I feel there can be three lines but how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by bisecting the perimeter?

Comment: Both become half i.e both become 12

Comment: To get the coordinates of A and B, put y=0 and x=o respectively, and try to proceed

Comment: That I have done.

Comment: @Maverick. Both can't become $12$. Because bisecting the triangle form a new side.

Comment: @Maverick, check the edited solution. Let me know if there is any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three conditions possible :

[image]

#### 1. $L$ intersects $OA$ and $AB$.

Area of $\displaystyle\triangle ACD=\frac{1}{2}(pq)\sin37^\circ=12\implies pq=40$. Also, $p+q=12$ for perimeter bisection.

Solve for $p,q$.

Do the same for other two cases

#### 2. $L$ intersects $OB$ and $AB$.

#### 3. $L$ intersects $OA$ and $OB$.

As corrected by @Moko19, also check the other three cases, too which I didn't mentioned in the diagram.

> You will get only one unique line passing through $D\displaystyle(0,\sqrt 6)$ and $\displaystyle C\left(\frac{24+4\sqrt 6}{5},\frac{12-3\sqrt 6}{5}\right)$ with slope $\displaystyle\frac{10-5\sqrt 6}{10}$.

Comment: Try to avoid posting incomplete answers

Comment: @Arjun, it is a hint.

Comment: For a generic triangle ABC, we have six possible lines: three possibilities where the line intersects a pair of sides and three where the line intersects a corner and the opposite side.  Not every one of these possibilities works for every triangle

Answer (score 3):

Let the line $L$ be $y= k x +b$ and it intersects with $6x+8y=48$ at $(p,q)$, where

$$p= \frac{24-4b}{3+4k },\>\>\>\>\> q= \frac{24k+3b}{3+4k } $$

Given the equal area and perimeter, establish the equations below

$$(6-b)p=bp+8q$$
$$(6-b)+\sqrt{p^2+(6-q)^2} = b+8+\sqrt{(8-p)^2+q^2}$$

Solve the system of equations above to obtain $b=\sqrt6$ and $k=1-\sqrt{\frac32}$. Thus, the bisecting line $L$ is

$$y= \left(1-\sqrt{\frac32}\right)x+\sqrt6$$

(Note that above equations corresponds to $L$ intersecting the vertical leg and the hypotenuse; other configurations do not yield valid solutions.)